# Gráfico de Gantt utilizando C3.js: Como utilizar axis Y category ou Y timeseries?

Tags: javascript, svg, gráfico, d3.js

Estou a procura de uma solução dentro da biblioteca javascript C3.JS (Baseada em D3.JS) onde eu consiga criar uma gráfico que mostre ao longo de um periodo os tipos de determinada coisa sendo usadas e intercaladas.

Um pequeno exemplo:
[image: Relevem o paint]
Bom, ja tentei utilizar

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    ...
    , axis: {
        y: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: ['Tipo 1', 'Tipo 2', 'Tipo 3', 'Tipo 4']
        }
    }
});
```

Isso não functionou, ao que me parece o c3 só suporta `type: 'category'` no `axis: { x: [...]`

Tentei também inverter e colocar o category no x, mas parece que o y também não suporta `type: 'timeseries'`.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        y: 'datas',
        [...]
    }
    [...]
    axis: {
        rotated: true,
        y: {
            type: 'timeseries'
        }
    }
});
```

Atualmente o que consegui fazer foi isso:
[image: Relevem as setas, meu inglês é péssimo]

(Não pude colocar c3.js e d3.js nas tags)

Comment: É um Gráfico de Gantt.

Comment: Você já considerou utilizar alguma biblioteca pronta, como http://taitems.github.io/jQuery.Gantt/ http://www.jsgantt.com/ ou http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/ ?

Comment: Não tinha considerado, mas parece ser uma saída. Vou tentar me ater a pelo menos o D3.JS. (http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5449641)

Comment: Talvez existam outras, estas aí que coloquei foram das primeiras listagens aqui que encontrei no Google. Encontrando alguma boa, você pode colocar como Resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var tasks = [
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:36:45 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 02:36:45 EST 2012"),"taskName":"E Job","status":"SUCCEEDED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:56:32 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:35:47 EST 2012"),"taskName":"A Job","status":"FAILED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:29:53 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:34:04 EST 2012"),"taskName":"D Job","status":"KILLED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 05:35:21 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 06:21:22 EST 2012"),"taskName":"P Job","status":"RUNNING"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 05:00:06 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 05:05:07 EST 2012"),"taskName":"D Job","status":"KILLED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:46:59 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 04:54:19 EST 2012"),"taskName":"P Job","status":"RUNNING"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:27:35 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:58:43 EST 2012"),"taskName":"E Job","status":"SUCCEEDED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:40:11 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:26:35 EST 2012"),"taskName":"A Job","status":"FAILED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:00:03 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 03:09:51 EST 2012"),"taskName":"D Job","status":"KILLED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:21:00 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 02:51:42 EST 2012"),"taskName":"P Job","status":"RUNNING"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 00:27:15 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 00:54:56 EST 2012"),"taskName":"E Job","status":"SUCCEEDED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 00:29:48 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 00:44:50 EST 2012"),"taskName":"D Job","status":"KILLED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 07:39:21 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 07:43:22 EST 2012"),"taskName":"P Job","status":"RUNNING"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 07:00:06 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 07:05:07 EST 2012"),"taskName":"D Job","status":"KILLED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:46:59 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 09:54:19 EST 2012"),"taskName":"P Job","status":"RUNNING"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:27:35 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:58:43 EST 2012"),"taskName":"E Job","status":"SUCCEEDED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:40:11 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:46:35 EST 2012"),"taskName":"A Job","status":"FAILED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:00:03 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 08:09:51 EST 2012"),"taskName":"D Job","status":"KILLED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 10:21:00 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 10:51:42 EST 2012"),"taskName":"P Job","status":"RUNNING"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 12:27:15 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 12:54:56 EST 2012"),"taskName":"E Job","status":"SUCCEEDED"},
{"startDate":new Date("Sat Dec 08 23:12:24 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 00:26:13 EST 2012"),"taskName":"A Job","status":"FAILED"}];

var taskStatus = {
    "SUCCEEDED" : "bar",
    "FAILED" : "bar-failed",
    "RUNNING" : "bar-running",
    "KILLED" : "bar-killed"
};

var taskNames = [ "D Job", "P Job", "E Job", "A Job"];

tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.endDate - b.endDate;
});
var maxDate = tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate;
tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.startDate - b.startDate;
});
var minDate = tasks[0].startDate;

var format = "%H:%M";

var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus).tickFormat(format);
gantt(tasks);
```

```css
html,body,#wrapper {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}
 
.chart {
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}
 
.axis path,.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
 
.bar {
 fill: #33b5e5;
}
 
.bar-failed {
 fill: #CC0000;
}
 
.bar-running {
 fill: #669900;
}
 
.bar-succeeded {
 fill: #33b5e5;
}
 
.bar-killed {
 fill: #ffbb33;
}
 
#forkme_banner {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
 z-index: 10;
 padding: 10px 50px 10px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 background:
  url('http://dk8996.github.io/Gantt-Chart/images/blacktocat.png')
  #0090ff no-repeat 95% 50%;
 font-weight: 700;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
 border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.tick text{
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.mentful.com/gantt-chart-d3v2.js"></script>
```

Usei a biblioteca [gantt-chart-d3.js](http://dk8996.github.io/Gantt-Chart/) junto com o [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) pra construir o gráfico.
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Haxz/pen/Lltjm)

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma diretiva do **Gantt** para **AngularJS**, talvez seja útil no seu projeto:

http://angular-gantt.github.io/angular-gantt/

Comment: Eu acabei usando uma classe php de gráficos (Mahatma Gantti)... Essa classe javascript "gantt-chart-d3.js" também não serve.

Answer (score 0):

Tive que fazer um relatório de Gantt e além do relatório adicionar algumas ações nele. Utilizei o AngularJS e existe essa diretiva:

https://github.com/angular-gantt/angular-gantt

Bem simples de se editar, facilitou muito meu trabalho.